# Which permissions does Eclipse need to run?

Tags: eclipse, permissions, windows-vista

I installed Eclipse and am having some trouble relating to denied user permissions.

I am working on Vista inside a Windows domain. My user account is very restricted. My boss needs to grant administrator permission any time I install any application or establish a new network connection through the firewall.

Here are some of the problems that have occurred:

- At Eclipse startup, Vista asks every time if I really want to run it. It doesn't remember my decision.
- Eclipse doesn't remember my default workspace.
- I installed the BIRT plugin. After a second restart it doesn't work anymore. The BIRT perspective does not run fine.

What permissions do I need to run Eclipse on Windows?

Answer (score 8):

This problem occurs when you host the Eclipse application within a directory that is protected by the Vista or Windows 7 operating system.  For example, `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, or `%ProgramW6432%`.  Unfortunately, for all of Eclipse's maturity, it still doesn't entirely restrict its per-user activities to the Windows operating system's user space.

If you don't care where your Eclipse application resides, or you don't have admin rights on your system, try moving the Eclipse application to a directory that is not protected by the Windows operating system.

If you have admin rights on your system, and want your Eclipse application to be hosted in one of Window's protected directories, you must make the directory writable to users.  This will allow the proper operation of the Eclipse application, but be warned that it will also allow users to directly modify files within the Eclipse application directory.  You can reduce this risk by making the directory writable to only the specific accounts that you choose.

Note that by performing either of the above solutions, it will not be necessary to run the Eclipse application with the "Run as Administrator" option.

To make the Eclipse application directory writable by users:

1. Right click on the Eclipse application directory within Windows Explorer.
2. Select "Properties".
3. Click the "Security" tab.
4. Click the "Edit..." button to change security permissions for the Eclipse folder.
5. If you want only specific user accounts to be able to write to the Eclipse application directory, click the "Add..." button to allow those accounts to appear within the "Group or user names" list.
6. One at a time, select each account to be granted write access to the Eclipse application directory, and then click the checkbox for "Modify / Allow" such that the checkbox is checked.
7. Conversely, if you want to allow all system users to be able to use Eclipse properly, select the "Users (YourComputerName\Users)" group from the "Group or user names" list, and then click the checkbox for "Modify / Allow" such that the checkbox is checked.
8. After all appropriate users have been given write access to the Eclipse application directory, click "OK".  You should now be able to run Eclipse without issue.

Answer (score 3):

[tharkun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4662073/3357935) is sort of correct but I just wanted to post a "more correct" answer for anyone else who finds this question in the future.

For some reason, Eclipse needs administrator privileges in Windows 7 and Windows Vista machines. To do this one time, right-click the Eclipse executable or shortcut and click "Run as administrator"; to make it permanent, go to properties, the compatibility tab, and check the "Run this program as an administrator" box.

Despite tharkun's post, perhaps he forgot, Eclipse doesn't have an installer; you simply unzip it. There is no reinstallation necessary. If you run Eclipse normally and find something wrong, and just discovered this answer, you can safely run Eclipse as administrator from now on and nothing will be broken as a result of you not having run as administrator up until this point.

The problems with Eclipse that require administrator mode do not show up immediately, but for example if you check for updates with Eclipse running in non-administrator mode, Eclipse will claim that there are no update sites available. Also some GUI features will have problems.

These problems are likely caused by some of the advanced UAC features meant to protect your system, such as [UAC Virtualization](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Protecting-System-Files-UAC-Virtualization-Part1.html). Eclipse can (and hopefully will) be fixed to write only to user space and "play nice" with other Windows applications, but for now we have to simply run it as administrator and trust that it's not taking advantage of the added privileges.

As a sidenote, I just spent several hours trying to figure out how to get Eclipse to write inside the %AppData% directory, in hopes that it would solve this problem and allow Eclipse to be run in user mode, but I could not get Eclipse to honor anything I tried. Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

### eclipse require write permission to app folder

it has to be in a folder with user write permission, f.e. **%localappdata%\Eclipse**. if u place it in %programfiles%\Eclipse it can't write to config files or plugins

the app has no installer. it stores config files in the app folder by default. the official install path is "c:\eclipse" and they forgot to mention that write permission is required

> https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation
>
> Decompress this file into the directory of your choice (e.g. "c:\eclipse" on Windows) and ensure you have full Read and Execute permissions.